# WPF | Attach a frame to more page

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, frame

I've got MainWindow in my WPF project, into this class there is a Frame.

```
<Window x:Class="Gestionale.MainWindow>
    <Grid>
        <Frame x:Name="frameChanger"/>
        <Button x:Name="Prenotation"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

When I click the button Add the frame shows the page Prenotation with this function:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{

private void Add_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        enabled_button();
        camereButton.IsEnabled = false;
        try
        {
            frameChanger.Navigate(new framePrenotation());
        }
        catch(Exception ex) { MessageBox.Show("Error!"); }
    }
}
```

The page prenotation has other 3 button:

```
<Page x:Name="Gestionale.AddPrenotation">
    <Grid>
        <Button x:Name="DeletePrenotation"/>
        <Button x:Name="AlterPrenotation"/>
        <Button x:Name="AddPrenotation"/>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

I need the frameChanger references to AddPrenotation page when I click on "AddPrenotation". How can I do it?

Any guidance will be appreciated

Thanks, Davide

Comment: So you need the page to add another instance of itself? im confused by wording

Comment: Well, I have a frame open and I work in it. In this frame there is a button that I won't that on click on this button the frame change with .navigation(Page p). But the instance of the principal frame is in the principal page, and I can't call the frame because isn't public static element. How can i do?

Answer (score 0):

try to write a constructor with parameter into the Page

```
frameChanger.Navigate(new framePrenotation(frameChanger));`
```

...

```
public partial class framePrenotation: Page
{
   private Frame frameParent; 
   public framePrenotation(Frame frame)
   {
      this.frameParent= frame;
      ...
   }
   ...
}
```

but I don't see why you should do something like that...